# Animate control based on other control

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am creating a media player application and I am trying to animate hiding the controls when the mouse is not inside the program window.

I have a animation setup and working, but I can't think of how to set the `EventTrigger` to the parent grid rather than the grid I actually want to animate. Essentially I want to set the `EventTrigger` to be `grdMain` and animate the height of `grdControls`.

Animation:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FadeInOut" TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="40" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Grids:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdMain" Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MediaElement x:Name="meVideo" IsMuted="True" Stretch="Uniform" MediaOpened="meVideo_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="meVideo_MediaEnded" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbVideoTimeline" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="7" Background="#252525" Foreground="Maroon" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" MouseDown="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseDown" MouseMove="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseMove" MouseUp="pgbVideoTimeline_MouseUp" />
        <Grid x:Name="grdControls" Grid.Row="2" Background="#0C0D0D" Height="0" Style="{StaticResource FadeInOut}" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stpPlaybackControls" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image x:Name="btnPlayPause" Height="30" Margin="10,0,5,0" ToolTip="Play" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Play.png" MouseEnter="btnVideoControl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnVideoControl_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnPlayPause_MouseUp" />
                <Image x:Name="btnReplay" Height="20" Margin="5,0,5,0" ToolTip="Replay" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Replay.png" MouseEnter="btnVideoControl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnVideoControl_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnReplay_MouseUp" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stpMiscControls" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                <Image x:Name="btnFullScreen" Height="25" Margin="5" ToolTip="Fullscreen" Source="Resources/Images/UI/FullScreen.png" MouseEnter="btnVideoControl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnVideoControl_MouseLeave" MouseUp="btnFullScreen_MouseUp" />
                <Image x:Name="btnSettings" Height="30" Margin="5,5,10,5" ToolTip="Settings" Source="Resources/Images/UI/Settings.png" MouseEnter="btnVideoControl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnVideoControl_MouseLeave" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm a WPF newbie, so don't know for sure. But could you put the style on the grdMain instead, and then have the TargetProperty reference the appropriate child control? E.g. something like "Storyboard.TargetProperty=grdControls.Height"? Alternatively, it looks like there's a "TargetName" property in a Storyboard. Maybe you can set that to "grdControls" (again, putting the style on the grdMain element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule when using `Trigger` (in case `TargetName` can't be used) is the Trigger should belong to the element which has the properties you want to modify. In this case the `Trigger` should belong to the `grdControls`. However you can use `DataTrigger` to walk up the tree and listen to some other property change of any visual upwards in the tree. The following code should work:

```
<Style x:Key="FadeInOut" TargetType="Grid">
   <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=grdMain}" 
                              Value="true">
           <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="40" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
           </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
           <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
               <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" 
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
           </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
       </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The second approach close to what *Peter Dunno* suggested in his comment requires you to have to set the `EventTrigger` ***directly*** in the `Triggers` property of the main Grid. You can either set the `Storyboard`s directly or define them as Resource. Here is the code for that approach:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdMain" Background="Black">
  <Grid.Triggers>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetName="grdControls">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="40" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetName="grdControls">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
  <!-- remaining code -->
</Grid>
```

Note that the `Style` you define now is no longer needed.

Comment: First approach works great, used that one because the other would have taken more rewriting but is one better practice than the other? Just so I know for future reference.

Comment: @blawford yes, the first one is better. I just included the second approach for reference.